# how we can take radionButtons id and value by post

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

```
@Html.RadioButton("BookType", "1", new { id = "100" })
<br>
Above code generates Below code
<br/>
< input id="100" name="BookType" type="radio" value="1" >
```

and the question is how can I  take the ID  and VALUE by 'POST' Action in the control.